# Getting unknown provider error when injecting a service into a controller during unit test with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to inject a service into an Angular unit test case but getting this error,

[$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=FactsSvcProvider%20%3C-%20FactsSvc

I understand the error, what i am not able to figure it out is why its not able to resolve the dependency?

Here is the snippet of code

app.js

```
    angular.module('numberApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ngMock'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
//config code...
})
```

SpecRunner.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.4.1</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.css">

  <script src="scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/boot.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script src="scripts/libraries/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/libraries/angular-mocks.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/libraries/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/libraries/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/facts-service.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/facts-controller.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/services/api-interceptor.service.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script src="scripts/controllers/facts-controller.spec.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

facts-controller.spec.js

```
describe('Test Controller', function () {
  var scope, controller, FactsSvc, $q;

  beforeEach(function() {
    angular.module('numberApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ngMock']);
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, $controller, _$q_, _factsSvc_) {
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $q = _$q_;
    FactsSvc = _factsSvc_;
    controller = $controller('factsCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      FactsSvc: FactsSvc
    });
  }));

  it('should call the generateMathFacts method in facts service to' +
      ' retrieve the facts',
    function() {
      var num = 20,
        response = {
          text: 'This is a fact'
        },
      dfd = $q.defer(),
      promise = dfd.promise();

      dfd.resolve(response);
      spyOn(FactsSvc, 'getMathFacts').andReturns(promise);

      scope.generateMathFact(num);
      expect(FactsSvc.getMathFacts).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I get this error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=factsSvcProvider%20%3C-%20factsSvc
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/angular.min.js:40:409
    at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/angular.min.js:38:394)
    at http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/angular.min.js:40:483
    at d (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/angular.min.js:38:394)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/angular.min.js:39:161)
    at Object.workFn (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/angular-mocks.js:2810:20)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js:1886:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js:1874:9)
Error: Declaration Location
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/angular-mocks.js:2778:25)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/scripts/controllers/facts-controller.spec.js:8:14)
    at addSpecsToSuite (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js:833:25)
    at Env.describe (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js:802:7)
    at jasmineInterface.describe (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js:3375:18)
    at http://localhost:8080/scripts/controllers/facts-controller.spec.js:1:1
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/scripts/controllers/facts-controller.spec.js:25:15)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js:1886:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js:1874:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js:1859:10)
    at Spec.Env.queueRunnerFactory (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js:697:35)
    at Spec.execute (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js:359:10)
    at Object.fn (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js:2479:37)
    at attemptAsync (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js:1916:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js:1871:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:8080/scripts/libraries/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js:1859:10)
```

controller code

```
"use strict"

angular.module('numberApp')
.controller('factsCtrl', function($scope, factsSvc, message, $rootScope) {
//logic...
})
```

service code

```
"use strict"

angular.module('numberApp')
.service('factsSvc', function($resource, resourceAPI) {
//logic...
}
```

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So.. I faced the same problem, got `unpr` error although all files were included. I found the solution at the end. For some strange reason, if you use `**/*.js` pattern in karma settings to include files, not all services, directives, ect. could be loaded. Try to include each file separately and point the full relative path to them.

Comment: Am not using karma. all the files are included in SpecRunner.html file